# Polylines in D3 and Legend spacing

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using the below example and wanted to have the legend outside the Pie chart and also have the Polyline for the Text and the count and Percentage for each slice.

With the current code I have Pie inside the pie and Text and Percentage are showing when I mouse over the slice.

Appreciate the help a lot.Thanks

Can some one please help as I am unable to move forward.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <style>
            #chart {
                height: 360px;
                margin: 0 auto; /* NEW */
                position: relative;
                width: 360px;
            }
    
            .tooltip {
                background: #eee;
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
                color: #333;
                display: none;
                font-size: 12px;
                left: 130px;
                padding: 10px;
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                top: 95px;
                width: 80px;
                z-index: 10;
            }
    
            .legend {
                font-size: 12px;
            }
    
            rect {
                cursor: pointer; /* NEW */
                stroke-width: 2;
            }
    
                rect.disabled { /* NEW */
                    fill: transparent !important; /* NEW */
                }
            /* NEW */
            h1 { /* NEW */
                font-size: 14px; /* NEW */
                text-align: center; /* NEW */
            }
            /* NEW */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script src="Scripts/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          (function(d3) {
            'use strict';
    
            var width = 360;
            var height = 360;
            var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
            var donutWidth = 75;
            var legendRectSize = 18;
            var legendSpacing = 4;
    
            var color = d3.scale.category20(); //builtin range of colors
    
            var svg = d3.select('#chart')
              .append('svg')
              .attr('width', width)
              .attr('height', height)
              .append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
                ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
    
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
              .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
              .outerRadius(radius);
    
            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
              .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
              .sort(null);
    
            var tooltip = d3.select('#chart')
              .append('div')
              .attr('class', 'tooltip');
    
            tooltip.append('div')
              .attr('class', 'label');
    
            tooltip.append('div')
              .attr('class', 'count');
    
            tooltip.append('div')
              .attr('class', 'percent');
    
            d3.csv('weekdays.csv', function(error, dataset) {
              dataset.forEach(function(d) {
                d.count = +d.count;
                d.enabled = true;                                         // NEW
              });
    
              var path = svg.selectAll('path')
                .data(pie(dataset))
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', arc)
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                  return color(d.data.label);
                })                                                        // UPDATED (removed semicolon)
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });                // NEW
    
              path.on('mouseover', function(d) {
                var total = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) {
                  return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0;                       // UPDATED
                }));
                var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10;
                tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.label);
                tooltip.select('.count').html(d.data.count);
                tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%');
                tooltip.style('display', 'block');
              });
    
              path.on('mouseout', function() {
                tooltip.style('display', 'none');
              });
    
              /* OPTIONAL
              path.on('mousemove', function(d) {
                tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 10) + 'px')
                  .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 10) + 'px');
              });
              */
    
              var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
                .data(color.domain())
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'legend')
                .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                  var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
                  var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
                  var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
                  var vert = i * height - offset;
                  return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
                });
    
              legend.append('rect')
                .attr('width', legendRectSize)
                .attr('height', legendRectSize)
                .style('fill', color)
                .style('stroke', color)                                   // UPDATED (removed semicolon)
                .on('click', function(label) {                            // NEW
                  var rect = d3.select(this);                             // NEW
                  var enabled = true;                                     // NEW
                  var totalEnabled = d3.sum(dataset.map(function(d) {     // NEW
                    return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0;                           // NEW
                  }));                                                    // NEW
    
                  if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') {                // NEW
                    rect.attr('class', '');                               // NEW
                  } else {                                                // NEW
                    if (totalEnabled < 2) return;                         // NEW
                    rect.attr('class', 'disabled');                       // NEW
                    enabled = false;                                      // NEW
                  }                                                       // NEW
    
                  pie.value(function(d) {                                 // NEW
                    if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled;           // NEW
                    return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0;                     // NEW
                  });                                                     // NEW
    
                  path = path.data(pie(dataset));                         // NEW
    
                  path.transition()                                       // NEW
                    .duration(750)                                        // NEW
                    .attrTween('d', function(d) {                         // NEW
                      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); // NEW
                      this._current = interpolate(0);                     // NEW
                      return function(t) {                                // NEW
                        return arc(interpolate(t));                       // NEW
                      };                                                  // NEW
                    });                                                   // NEW
                });                                                       // NEW
    
              legend.append('text')
                .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
                .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
                .text(function(d) { return d; });
    
            });
    
          })(window.d3);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you provide your `weekdays.csv`?

Comment: label,             count            
Active_Integrated,286
Active_not_Integrated,56
Assigned,19
Assigned_Waiting,13
Complete,184
Dev_Waiting,17
Global_Screening,23
In Progress,14
In_Development,12
New,76
Pending_CTL_Approval,38
Rejected,50
RETIRED,37
Test,1
Testing,3

Comment: Hi any insight on my request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place the legends where ever you wish by making the legends in a group and placing it using the `translate`

First Make SVG:

```
  var s = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

Now make a legend group:

```
  var legend_group = s.append('g').attr('transform',
    'translate(' + (width / 3) + ',' + (height / 1.4) + ')');
```

Use translate it to a place of your choice. I have moved it to `(width/3, height/1.4)`

Make a group in which the pie chart will be drawn.

```
  var svg = s.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
      ',' + (radius) + ')');
```

Lets make a polyline for each slice:
This function will make as many polylines as the dataset length.

```
function makePolyLines() {
  var polyline = svg.selectAll("polyline")
    .data(pie(dataset), key);

  polyline.enter()
    .append("polyline");
  //hide polyline for which value is 0, a case when legend is clicked.
  svg.selectAll("polyline").style("display", function(d) {
    if (d.value == 0) {
      return "none";
    } else {
      return "block";
    }
  });

  polyline.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("points", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
      };
    });

  polyline.exit()
    .remove();
}
```

Similarly make text for labels.

```
function makeTexts() {
  var text = svg.selectAll(".labels")
    .data(pie(dataset), key);

  text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .classed("labels", true)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label + " (" + d.data.count + ")";
    });
  //hide text for which value is 0, a case when legend is clicked.
  svg.selectAll(".labels").style("display", function(d) {
    if (d.value == 0) {
      return "none";
    } else {
      return "block";
    }
  });

  text.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {

      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      };
    });

  text.exit()
    .remove();
}
```

finally call these two functions.

1) initially after the data is fetched.

2) whenever legend is clicked and the piechart is updated.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAbnep00GMRkx5Xey6gL?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome .. it rocks.. where can we change the Polyline color and the text color of the legend too..

Comment: polyline color can be edited in the style 
    `polyline {
      opacity: .3;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      fill: none;
    }`
and label text in labels class
`    .labels{
      fill: blue;
    }`
http://plnkr.co/edit/sAbnep00GMRkx5Xey6gL?p=preview

Comment: Awesome and rocks.. Can we call the data from Web API or web service instead of csv file.. Please advise.thanks..

Comment: yeah you can do an ajax to load your data from WEB API

Comment: Sure I will try that route and get back.. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to place the legend to the right/left hand side of the pie.. but no luck..Changed the Offset in the code.. please advise..

Comment: Like i mentioned in my answer above the legend is a group you can translate it to where ever you wish offset will not work...something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/yAnytCQ8jSCOPTe4BiAH?p=preview

Comment: Tried WEB API for passing instead of CSV..     $(function () {
            var chartData = [];
            var colors = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "api/PieChart",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (i,j) {
                        console.log(result); // server response
                        chartData = result; //
                    });
                    console.log(chartData);

Comment: Looks like I am missing something.. Can you please advise..thanks

Comment: doesnt appear to be a problem are you getting errors on server?

Comment: I am passing the chartdata in the place of CSV file.. but nothing shows up.. not generating a pie..

Comment: I am presuming you are passing the json in the same format expected by the code.
This is the section which reads you csv into expected JSON.
I would suggest that since this is a diffrent question kindly post a fresh question to get better results.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to make the `svg` element wider. Currently it's `var width = 360;`, you can change it to `var width = 700;` for example.

After you gained some more space, determine the width of the legend, for the example let's use 300px. Declare a new variable: `var legendWidth = 300;`

Now, when the legend is being declared:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
      var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
      var horz = (-2 * legendRectSize);
      var vert = i * height - offset;
      return 'translate(' + (horz) + ',' + vert + ')';
    });
```

When calculation to horizontal translation, we need to take the `legendWidth` into consideration:

```
var horz = (-2 * legendRectSize) - legendWidth;
```

Note: You will need to fix the `left` and `top` CSS properties for the `.tooltip` element.

Another note: If you want to take this solution to the next level, you can implement it in a dynamic way instead of having the "magic number" of `var legendWidth = 300`.

Comment: Hi .. thanks for the reply.. I now have the legend outside of the donut.Can you please suggest in having tool tip showing with a ployline as requested in the question.Appreciate the time.

Comment: If you follow the changes I stated (there are three of them) the legend would be in the right side of the circle, and not in the middle of it.

Comment: Yes It is outside of the donut as I replied.Thank you so much.Is it possible to have the animation for Pie.As it is showing as pie directly on page load...I believe the attrtweenis not working.. as it should draw a pie as a animation on the page load correct?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not an expert in animations, I cannot help you with that. In my opinion it's not in the scope of this question, I suggest you ask a different question about it.

Comment: Ok Thanks.Is there any chance I can get help with drawing polyline for each pie slice and append the count and percentage to it  as requested in the question.Thanks again.