# How to wrap D3 labels with ticks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I am trying to get my labels to wrap correctly. I need to get the ticks and labels to match up. I am using a wrap function for the labels but could not get it to work with the tspans.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-forked-nhh85?file=/src/index.js)

UPDATE

Here is before and after picture to help understand what Im after.

[image: BEFORE AFTER]

Comment: Add a 'legend' block aside the pie (colors and labels). Show labels on hover of pie segments

Comment: can you add a pic of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: sure give me a few minutes

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi see update please

Comment: I think this might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662554/polylines-in-d3-and-legend-spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is no simple way to get SVG `<text>` elements' content to wrap like it would in HTML. However I did find [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784302/wrapping-text-in-d3) which suggests using the [D3 Plus](https://github.com/d3plus/d3plus) library to add text wrapping to D3.

If for some reason that isn't an option you will probably have to calculate the wrapping yourself, it is a bit of a nasty process but is doable with some effort. In general terms you need to:

1. Create an HTML element with the same width and font styles as the target SVG text
2. Add the desired content to this element word-by-word
3. After adding each word check the height of the HTML element, if it has increased you know you need a newline before that word
4. Once you know how many lines it needs use `<tSpan>` elements to output each line of text (you'll have to manually set the top offset for each new line)

I'd definitely advise using the library though if at all possible!